# Merge conditional dataframe rows repeating values

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, merge

I have one dataframe (X) that looks like

```
label1  label2
1        2
1        3
1        4
2        1
2        3
2        4
```

And another (Y) that looks like

```
label  COLONY
1       5
2       5     
3       5
4       6
```

I have compared the labels in dataframe X to Y if they are in the same colony listed in dataframe Y and made a new dataframe with this line:

```
Z <- transform(X, SAME.COLONY = Y$COLONY[match(X$label1, Y$label)] == Y$COLONY[match(X$label2, Y$label)])
```

```
label1    label2  SAME.COLONY
1           2        TRUE
1           3        TRUE
1           4        FALSE
2           1        TRUE
2           3        TRUE
2           4        FALSE
3           4        FALSE
```

Now I am looking to import a new column from dataframe Y into Z with the group value only if Z$SAME.COLONY==T and the one of the label numbers match, but this isn't working for me:

```
Z$COLONY<- ifelse(Z$SAME.COLONY == T && Z$label1 == Y$label, Y$COLONY, NA)
```

I get this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In Z$label1 == Y$label :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

This may be becuase label values are repeated multiple time in Z$label1 and Z$label2 but I'm not sure how to account for this?

Reproduce data:

```
X=data.frame(label1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3),  label2=c(2,3,4,1,3,4,4))
Y=data.frame(label=c(1,2,3,4),  COLONY=c(5,5,5,6))

Z <- transform(X, 
  SAME.COLONY = 
    Y$COLONY[match(X$label1, Y$label)] == 
      Y$COLONY[match(X$label2, Y$label)]
)
```

Comment: Your `Z` definition doesn't work with the sample data provided. I get `Error in data.frame(list(label1 = 1:3, label2 = 2:4), SAME.COLONY = logical(0)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0`. (I used `read.table` to read in your `X` and `Y`.) Could you additionally share `dput(X)` and `dput(Y)` so we can use your exact sample?

Comment: Oh, I see, you changed the column names. `COLONY` in your sample data, `colony` in your code. They need to match, R is case-sensitive. But then the `Z` result has only 3 rows, it does not match what you show in the question. Please make things reproducible and clear.

Comment: Apologies it should be updated now?

Answer (score 1):

We may do a join

```
library(dplyr)
Z <- left_join(Z, Y, by = c("label1" = "label")) %>%
    mutate(COLONY = case_when(SAME.COLONY~ COLONY))
```

-output

```
Z
  label1 label2 SAME.COLONY COLONY
1      1      2        TRUE      5
2      1      3        TRUE      5
3      1      4       FALSE     NA
4      2      1        TRUE      5
5      2      3        TRUE      5
6      2      4       FALSE     NA
7      3      4       FALSE     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, a solution can be by using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

# 7 don't exist in Y$label
X=data.frame(label1=c(7,1,1,2,2,2,3),  label2=c(2,3,4,1,3,4,4))
Y=data.frame(label=c(1,2,3,4),  COLONY=c(5,5,5,6))


Z=X%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  # check if COLONY of label1 is the same of COLONY of label2
  mutate(SAME.COLONY = ifelse(label1%in% Y$label && label2%in%Y$label,
                              (Y[Y$label == label1, ]$COLONY == Y[Y$label == label2, ]$COLONY),
                              NA
                              )
  )%>%
  # get COLONY if True
  mutate(COLONY=ifelse(SAME.COLONY==T,Y[Y$label==label1,]$COLONY,NA))

Z
# > Z
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Rowwise: 
# label1 label2 SAME.COLONY COLONY
# <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>        <dbl>
# 7      2  NA              NA
# 1      3 TRUE             5
# 1      4 FALSE           NA
# 2      1 TRUE             5
# 2      3 TRUE             5
# 2      4 FALSE           NA
# 3      4 FALSE           NA
```

Comment: I am still getting an error, again probably becuase of the repeats in my dataframes: 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `SAME.COLONY`.
i `SAME.COLONY = (...)`.
i `SAME.COLONY` must be size 1, not 0.
i Did you mean: `SAME.COLONY = list((...))` ?
i The error occurred in row 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: this error occurs when **label1 or label2 of X is not exist in label of Y**. i edited the code to put `SAME.COLONY = NA` if that is the case.
or what do you expect if label1 or label2 don't exist?